# generate 2 DatePickers Dynamically

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am devoloping a reactive form that have a section called experience it has a start date and an end date.
am trying to generate the 2 datepickers along with the input (for experience "title").
when using an index I get an error  :"datepicker is not a function "
this is my code for the moment :

```html
<div  *ngFor=" let exp of proExperience;
                            let i = index;
                            trackBy: trackByFn
                        ">

                <div *ngFor="let column of columns; let i=index">
                    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="i" placeholder="Start {{column.label}}" name="{{column.name}}">
                    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="i"></button>
                    <md-datepicker #i></md-datepicker>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: `#i` is not doing what you think it is

Comment: apparently not :p i see it now